# I have Drupal Site with Load balancer installed, How to configure Apache Solr for all the slaves?

Tags: drupal, load-balancing, solr

I am searching for this solution from last week [may be I am not searching in proper way.. :( ]
I have Drupal Site on which uses Load Balancer. I have installed Apache solr on its Master server successfully but could not figure out how to make the apache solr work for other two slaves.

Are there any settings or modules, or I'll have to make some customizations in any files?

If anyone has done this, please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Configure Solr (actually its web container) to accept connections from all your master and slaves servers. In `admin/settings/apachesolr/settings`, configure the host of your Solr server using its IP address of hostname, but not *localhost*.

Comment: "Configure Solr (actually its web container) to accept connections from all your master and slaves servers. "
I have 3 Servers and have installed Solr Servers on all the three of them. How do I make 1 of them master and other two as slaves? Also, how to to accept connections from all master and slaves servers?
Thanks for your reply !!

Comment: Solr itslef does not deal with master-slaves. You can distribute a Solr install on multiple hosts and use it to ensure availability of the Solr service, but you need to do it at the web container level. Each web container (Tomcat, Jetty, Resin, JBoss, etc.) has it own way to handle distibuted deployment.